# Filtering by plain date SQL to Linq syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL and result:

```
SELECT EventTime FROM Incidents
-- RESULT --
2015-10-20 00:00:00.000
2015-10-20 05:00:00.000
2015-10-20 05:50:00.000
2015-10-20 07:00:00.000
2015-10-20 09:00:30.000
2015-10-21 05:00:00.000
2015-10-21 06:10:00.000
2015-10-22 09:10:00.000
```

I use the following SQL to filter by plain date (SQL 2014):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (Date, [EventTime]) AS EventDate FROM Incidents
-- RESULT --
EventDate
2015-10-20
2015-10-21
2015-10-22
```

So very easy in SQL. For LINQ I try the logic:

```
var q = db.TimeLines.Select(x => x.Time.Date).Distinct();
// show it
q.ToList().ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine("EventDate: {0}", x); });
```

Breaks with: Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ...

...How to write the second SQL in LINQ?

Comment: are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: For LINQ-to-SQL, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663523/using-built-in-sql-functions-in-a-linq-query). For Entity Framework, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412231/how-do-i-perform-date-part-comparison-in-ef).

Comment: Check out [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The correct Linq try is: var q = db.Incidents.Select(x => x.EventTime.Date).Distinct();

Comment: If you change it into a list before getting the datepart it will work, db.TimeLines.ToList().Select(x => x.Time.Date).Distinct();

Comment: Yes Nick. But this populate the result before the apply filter... the table can have many records

Comment: You aren't applying any filters? If you want to apply criteria before working with the list in memory, use a .Where before the .ToList

Comment: would be nice if you marked my answer as the answer, considering you have indicated it worked for you..

Answer (score 1):

If you change the query into a list before using operators that aren't translatable to sql, then it will work.

```
var q = db.TimeLines.ToList.Select(x => x.Time.Date).Distinct();
// show it
q.ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine("EventDate: {0}", x); });
```

But you need to cast as a list before you get the date portion of the date, not after.

**EDIT:**

In this case, i'm not sure you will get any performance increase at all, but as mentioned in the comment below by juharr, use AsEnumerable if you want the query to remain lazy.

```
var q = db.TimeLines.AsEnumerable.Select(x => x.Time.Date).Distinct();
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want to run the query entirely on the SQL server, you can use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` as a translatable function:

```
var q = db.TimeLines.Select(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Time)).Distinct();
```

**EDIT 3:**
Also, Sergey is right about my first example, you should select just what you want before dumping into memory if doing it this way:

```
var q = db.TimeLines.Select(x => x.Time).AsEnumerable.Select( x => x.Date).Distinct();
```

Comment: You could also use `AsEnumerable` so that the query isn't run until the resulting `IEnumerable` is iterated.

Comment: mean? var q = db.TimeLines.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Time.Date).Distinct();

Comment: Dumping whole datatable to memory is not best idea

Comment: well, there's your third option in there too for doing it all on the db side.

Comment: EDIT 2 Works perfect.

Comment: yeah it's the best performing one too, but the first answer should help you more understand what the error message you were getting was

Comment: @harveyt were you going to mark this as the answer then?